# libtorch (PyTorch C++) weird class syntax

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

In the official PyTorch C++ examples on GitHub [Here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/cpp/custom-dataset/custom-dataset.cpp)
you can witness a strange definition of a class:

```
class CustomDataset : public torch::data::datasets::Dataset<CustomDataset> {...}
```

My understanding is that this defines a class `CustomDataset` which "inherits from" or "extends" `torch::data::datasets::Dataset<CustomDataset>`. This is weird to me since the class we're creating is inheriting from another class which is parameterized by the class we're creating...How does this even work? What does it mean? This seems to me like an `Integer` class inheriting from `vector<Integer>`, which seems absurd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the [curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), or CRTP for short. A major advantage of this technique is that it enabled so-called *static polymorphism*, meaning that functions in `torch::data::datasets::Dataset` can call into functions of `CustomDataset`, without needing to make those functions virtual (and thus deal with the runtime mess of virtual method dispatch and so on). You can also perform compile-time metaprogramming such as compile-time `enable_if`s depending on the properties of the custom dataset type.

In the case of PyTorch, [`BaseDataset`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/datasets/base.h) (the superclass of `Dataset`) uses this technique heavily to support operations such as mapping and filtering:

> ```
>   template <typename TransformType>
>   MapDataset<Self, TransformType> map(TransformType transform) & {
>     return datasets::map(static_cast<Self&>(*this), std::move(transform));
>   }
> ```

Note the static cast of `this` to the derived type (legal as long as CRTP is properly applied); `datasets::map` constructs a `MapDataset` object which is also parametrized by the dataset type, allowing the `MapDataset` implementation to statically call methods such as `get_batch` (or encounter a *compile-time* error if they do not exist).

Furthermore, since `MapDataset` receives the custom dataset type as a type parameter, compile-time metaprogramming is possible:

> ```
>   /// The implementation of `get_batch()` for the stateless case, which simply
>   /// applies the transform to the output of `get_batch()` from the dataset.
>   template <
>       typename D = SourceDataset,
>       typename = torch::disable_if_t<D::is_stateful>>
>   OutputBatchType get_batch_impl(BatchRequestType indices) {
>     return transform_.apply_batch(dataset_.get_batch(std::move(indices)));
>   }
>
>   /// The implementation of `get_batch()` for the stateful case. Here, we follow
>   /// the semantics of `Optional.map()` in many functional languages, which
>   /// applies a transformation to the optional's content when the optional
>   /// contains a value, and returns a new optional (of a different type)  if the
>   /// original optional returned by `get_batch()` was empty.
>   template <typename D = SourceDataset>
>   torch::enable_if_t<D::is_stateful, OutputBatchType> get_batch_impl(
>       BatchRequestType indices) {
>     if (auto batch = dataset_.get_batch(std::move(indices))) {
>       return transform_.apply_batch(std::move(*batch));
>     }
>     return nullopt;
>   }
> ```

Notice that the conditional enable is dependent on `SourceDataset`, which we only have available because the dataset is parametrized with this CRTP pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd been staring at this all day wondering if it was a dumb question. C++ is so confusing to me coming from Python. I want to be able to write fast code, but I also want to be able to see the beauty in the code. I guess I'm not quite there yet with C++.

Comment: No worries! I'm glad I could help and hope that my explanation was sufficiently clear (I'm afraid that I may have muddled through the pytorch-specific stuff)

Comment: Even if I don't fully understand everything you said, I at least have some idea now and have a keyword to google. Sometimes that's the hardest part...